# How to write an equation with a variable in legend?

Tags: r, plot, legend, equation

I am trying to write an equation like "R^2=0.00575" in the legend, and the number 0.00575 can be embedded in the legend automatically. Here is an example.

```
set.seed(100)
x=rnorm(100)
y=1:100
fit=lm(y~x)
R_squared=format(summary(fit)$r.squared,digits = 3)
plot(x,y,type="l")
legend("topleft",legend =expression(R^{2}~"="~R_squared),bty = "n")
```

[image]

As the figure shows, the variable `"R_squared"` is not embedded in the equation. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this task I think it is best to do `parse(text=sprintf(...))`. You can code the R language syntax into the string literal to be parsed into an R expression using [`parse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html), and use [`sprintf()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) format specifications to embed any numeric or string values that are stored in variables into the expression.

```
set.seed(100L);
x <- rnorm(100L);
y <- 1:100;
fit <- lm(y~x);
R_squared <- format(summary(fit)$r.squared,digits=3L);
plot(x,y,type='l');
legend('topleft',legend=parse(text=sprintf('paste(R^2,\' = %s\')',R_squared)),bty='n');
```

An alternative syntax that leverages the fact that `==` is plotted as a single equal sign:

```
legend('topleft',legend=parse(text=sprintf('R^2 == %s',R_squared)),bty='n');
```

See the [plotmath documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).

[image: plot]

Comment: What an amazing and wonderful answer! For me, I do not even know the `parse` function. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, just one more question, what does `%s` mean in `text=sprintf('R^2 == %s',R_squared)`? Thanks.

Comment: It's the format specification for the string which will be substituted by the value of `R_squared`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `bquote`:

```
set.seed(100L);
x <- rnorm(100L);
y <- 1:100;
fit <- lm(y~x);
R_squared <- format(summary(fit)$r.squared,digits=3L);
plot(x,y,type='l');
legend('topleft',legend=bquote(R^{2} ~ "=" ~ .(R_squared)),bty='n');
```

More information on partial substitution of expressions with `bquote` can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bquote.html), which defines the function as:

> An analogue of the LISP backquote macro. bquote quotes its argument
>   except that terms wrapped in .() are evaluated in the specified where
>   environment.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks. I am not familiar with `expression` in R.

Comment: I wonder why you add `.` before “(R_squared)” in `legend=bquote(R^{2} ~ "=" ~ .(R_squared)),bty='n')`. Is there any document about this? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang, see edited information added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!